# How to do MySQL COUNT depending on some condition

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I have 5 tables related to each other. I have a JOIN query gathering all data. I am starting by providing cpv_id as a variable coming from users. Through several tables in between, every company is related with that cpv_id. Every company has its status, which can be 1, 2 or 3. Those statuses are changing, and I need to get percentage of companies having status of "3" ( but related to this cpv_id provided ).

Basically, this is the flow:

I get *cpv_id* from users, I find it in **club_offer_cpv** table and I get *club_offer_id* so I can connect to **club_offer** table. Then in club_offer table I get *club_id* so I can connect to **club** table. Then in **club** table I get *users_id* so I can connect to **users** table. Then in **users** table I get *company_id* so I can connect to last **company_status** table ( **company_status** have foreign key *company_id* too ). **company_status** is where I need to get my data from. And I need this:

Here I have 2 field of interest: **company_status** and **tstamp**.

**company_status** is storing status for each company, and it is changing over time. People who created database before me, made is so every time when status updates new row is inserted with new status. And status with latest **tstamp** is displayed to end users. What I need to do is to show users percent of companies having status of "3". To do that I need to get number of all statuses for all companies, and number of status "3" for all that have it. Problem is that some company may have status "3" but after that it got status "2" ( it has changed ). Because of that I should somehow get only status where tstamp is the latest, since the newest status will have latest timestamp. So if some company have both status "2" and status "3", but status "2" comes after status "3", I should not count her. I should count only companies that has status "3" as latest. Here comes my trouble, because I do not know how to do this condition.

On SQL Fiddle you will see what I have so far. So I need one query that will count all latest statuses ( 1, 2 or 3 ). And then I need query that will count only latest "3" statuses, so I can say something like **70% of companies have status "3"**. *This is the goal*. **Calculating percent of companies having status "3"**.

You can find SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3e296/4

Can anyone help me out with this ? Thank you

Comment: You mean, Calculating percent of companies having newest status "3".

Answer (score 2):

Here a query that would do what you want :

```
select count(*) as 'Total of status in 1,2,3', (sum(company_status.status = 3) / count(*)) * 100 as 'Percentage of status 3'
from company_status
join users using(company_id)
join club on users.id = club.users_id
join club_offer on club.id = club_offer.club_id
join club_offer_cpv on club_offer.id = club_offer_id
where club_offer_cpv.cpv_id like '66%'
  and company_status.status in(1,2,3);
```

Remember, `sum` in MySQL will return 1 if true else 0, so it is useful for conditional count.

This would output

```
TOTAL OF STATUS IN 1,2,3    PERCENTAGE OF STATUS 3
28                          92.8571
```

for your fiddle.

I am not sure if the part of *latest*  status is correct as you did not precise what you meant by latest, but the hardest part is done and I'm pretty sure you can achieve the rest if this is not correct.

Comment: Thank you. By latest I mean that companies may have status 2 and 3, but only one is valid, one that has latest timestamp ( newer date ). So if some company had status of 3 yesterday, but today it has changed to 2, previous status 3 should not be counted when calculating percentage. Field tstamp is holding date and time of change. And I do not know how to take that in count.

Comment: @Anita Write a query for the date of the newest status, ie select max(tstamp) from ... . Then use it as a subquery to select rows with status=3 and tstamp=(*subquery*).

Comment: I have tried it like this, but it is not working. It will not select only statuses with the newest timestamp. `select distinct(company_status.company_id), company_status.status, company_status.tstamp

from company_status
join users using(company_id)
join club on users.id = club.users_id
join club_offer on club.id = club_offer.club_id
join club_offer_cpv on club_offer.id = club_offer_id
where club_offer_cpv.cpv_id like '66%'
  and company_status.status in(1,2,3)
  AND company_status.tstamp = (SELECT max(tstamp));`